# Replace leading whitespace with sed (or similar)

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I'd like to replace the leading space or tab characters on each line of a file with a like-number of other characters (let's use _ for simplicity).

E.g.

```
foo bar
 foo bar
  line 3
```

becomes

```
foo bar
_foo bar
__line 3
```

Note that non-leading whitepsace is not affected, otherwise this would be easy!  I suspect it's still easy, but I'm missing the trick.

Comment: Does a tab get replaced with a single '_', or enough to fill out a tabstop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
sed ':a;s/^\([[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]/\1_/;ta' file
```

#### Example

```
$ sed ':a;s/^\([[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]/\1_/;ta' <<<$'foo bar\n foo bar\n\t\tline 3\n _ x'
foo bar
_foo bar
__line 3
__ x
```

Comment: If a line already starts with one or more underscores followed by blanks, this adds underscores where it shouldn't.  It is relatively easily rescuable, though: `sed '/^[[:space:]]/{:a;s/\(_*\)[[:space:]]/\1_/;ta;}'`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, good call on that, answer updated. One small change in that the `^` anchor will still be needed inside the `s` command to prevent spaces between words to turn into underscores.

Comment: Typo in transcribing my amended `sed` script.  :(  It's tough getting everything right, sometimes.

Comment: You don't need to exclude leading underscores in the regex, you can just look for whitespace: `{:a;s/^\([[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]/\1_/;ta}`

Comment: The current version is still slightly broken; something like `' _ x'` will become `'___x'` rather than `'__ x'`. (Glenn Jackman's suggestion would fix that.)

Comment: Thanks @glenn, looking for [[:space:]] zero or more times in a loop is definitely the way to go for this problem

Answer (score 3):

Are you O.K. with a Perl one-liner? You can write:

```
perl -pe 's/^([ \t]+)/"_" x length $1/e'
```

(either piping in your file on standard-input, or specifying a filename at the end of the cmomand).

**Edited to add:** William Pursell, in a comment above, asks whether you want "a tab get replaced with a single '_', or enough to fill out a tabstop". The above command would replace a tab with a single underscore. If you want enough to fill out a tabstop, the simplest approach is to use the `expand` utility, which converts tabs to spaces, before passing the input to Perl:

```
expand -i | perl -pe 's/^([ \t]+)/"_" x length $1/e'
```

(either piping in your file on standard-input, or specifying a filename at the end of the `expand` part, just before the `|` character).

Comment: Couldn't use perl in this case, but upvote for a working solution anyway which shows an interesting (and probably way more efficient than the sed one) solution.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/^\s\+/!b;h;s///;x;s/\S.*//;s/./_/g;G;s/\n//' <<<$'foo bar\n foo bar\n\t\tline 3'
foo bar
_foo bar
__line 3
```

To expand initial tabs to spaces and then to underscores:

```
expand -i <<<$'foo bar\n foo bar\n\t\tline 3' |
sed '/^\s\+/!b;h;s///;x;s/\S.*//;s/./_/g;G;s/\n//'
foo bar
_foo bar
________________line 3
```

Answer (score 0):

@SiegeX’s solution doesn’t work with the system `sed` on Mac OS X Lion. Here’s one workaround:

```
eval sed "$(for i in $(seq 40 -1 1); do
                  echo -n "-e 's/^$(for j in $(seq 1 $i);
                      do echo -n ' ';
                  done)/$(for j in $(seq 1 $i);
                      do echo -n '_';
                  done)/' "; done)"
```

which dynamically generates the options

```
...
-e 's/^       /_______/g' \
-e 's/^      /______/g' \
-e 's/^     /_____/g' \
-e 's/^    /____/g' \
-e 's/^   /___/g' \
-e 's/^  /__/g' \
-e 's/^ /_/g'
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this regex for getting the leading white space or tab characters

```
(^\s+)
```

but replacing it with an underscore, well that i can't help cause i have no experience in bash